# MySQL InnoDB FULLTEXT index randomly ignores record

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds, full-text-indexing, aws-aurora-serverless

I have a fulltext index on an InnoDB table that, for the most part, works fine. Searches return accurate results and scores seem reasonable.

Yesterday there was a single, seemingly random row that was inserted into the table but that would not turn up in any search results. Even running boolean searches that should have exclusively returned that row failed to return it.

I deleted and rebuilt the index, and now it's working correctly (the row in question does return from searches now).

Can anyone suggest a reason why this might have happened so I can prevent it in the future?

The database is running on AWS Aurora Serverless, if it matters.

Comment: If you can reproduce it, file a bug:  bugs.mysql.com